# Get PK value by passing in non-PK value using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on building a Windows Phone 8.1 app that uses a Web API and Entity Framework to connect to a SQL database.  With my current setup, I have data objects for my entities in my services project (which contain the PK id property) and models in my phone client project (which don't contain the PK id property in order to enable auto-increment when a new member is created.  I'm trying to write a services method that returns the memberID value (PK of Member entity) when the username is passed to it.  However, when I do so, I get the following error:

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.Http.StreamContent' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

I'm not sure if I'm trying to do something that doesn't work, or if there's a much easier way to do this, but my code builds successfully.  The above error is a run-time error.  Here's the code I'm using for my relevant classes:

This is the method that calls my server from my client's backend:

```
public async void GetMembers(String currUser, String currPass)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //MembersListBox.Items.Add("using block entered");
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://nflff.azurewebsites.net");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            //MembersListBox.Items.Add("client's defaultrequestheaders done");

            //gets all members from table
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Members");
            //MembersListBox.Items.Add("after response reached");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //reads all member objs from table as a json string
                string s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //how can we pass the user's login credentials (including ID) to other pages? via HttpClient?
                //converts string of members into a list of member objs
                var deserializedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Members>>(s);
                foreach (Members member in deserializedResponse)
                {
                    //if current member matches a member found in list
                    if(member.compareUserAndPassword(currUser, currPass)) {
                        MembersListBox.Items.Add(currUser + " and " + currPass + " found.");
                        MembersListBox.Items.Add(member.userName + " " + member.password);
                        Members currMember = member; //this works
                        MembersListBox.Items.Add("Current member: " + currMember.ToString());
                        //how should memberID be remembered for user?
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = CreateBasicHeader(currUser, currPass);
                        MembersListBox.Items.Add(client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization);
                        HttpResponseMessage memResponse = await client.GetAsync("api/Members/" + currUser);
                        if (memResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            MembersListBox.Items.Add("memResponse successful");
                        }
                        //should only go to home page if successful
                        //int memID = Convert.ToInt32(await client.GetAsync("api/Members?MemberStr=" + currUser));
                        HttpResponseMessage thisMember = await client.GetAsync("api/Members?MemberStr=" + currUser);
                        var con = thisMember.Content;
                        var head = thisMember.Headers;
                        var rm = thisMember.RequestMessage;
                        int memID = Convert.ToInt32(thisMember.Content);//THIS IS THE LINE THAT GENERATES THE ERROR
                        //will need to call server's getidbyname method and pass result instead of currMember.memberID
                        //this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(HomeHub), currMember.memberID);
                        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(HomeHub), memID);
                    }

                }

            }
            //MembersListBox.Items.Add(Members.MembersList.Count);
            foreach (var member in Members.MembersList)
            {
               // MembersListBox.Items.Add(member.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my controller from my services project:

```
public class MembersController : ApiController
{
    private GatoradeShowerDB db = new GatoradeShowerDB();

    // GET: api/Members
    public IQueryable<Member> GetMembers()
    {
        return db.Members;
    }

    // GET: api/Members/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Member))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMember(int id)
    {
        Member member = await db.Members.FindAsync(id);
        if (member == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(member);
    }

    //GET: api/Members?MemberStr={memberStr}
    [ResponseType(typeof(Member))]
    public async Task<T> GetMemberIDByName<T>(String MemberStr) where T : struct
    {
        //var member = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Member>(MemberStr);
        //Member member = await db.Members.FindAsync(MemberStr);
        //var userId = ...;
        var member = await db.Members.Where(x => x.UserName == MemberStr).ToListAsync();
        if (member == null)
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(NotFound(), typeof(T));
        }
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(member[0].MemberID, typeof(T));
        //return member[0].MemberID; //hopefully gets id of first member in async list and returns it
        //return Ok(member);
    }

//other methods
}
```

Also, here's my client-side model:

```
public class Members
{
    //[JsonProperty("MemberID")]
    //public int memberID { get; private set; }
    [JsonProperty("FirstName")]
    private string firstName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("LastName")]
    private string lastName { get; set; } //both names should be optional
    [JsonProperty("UserName")]
    public string userName { get; private set; } //note: I don't think we should track first and last names
    [JsonProperty("Password")]
    public string password { get; private set; } //will probably need to implement validation in setter so won't be able to auto-implement
    [JsonProperty("Email")]
    private string email { get; set; }//same with this. will need validation
    [JsonProperty("MemberCity")]
    private string memberCity { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("MemberState")]
    private string memberState { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("MemberZip")]
    private string memberZip { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("MemberPhone")]
    private string memberPhone { get; set; }//should also be optional
    [JsonProperty("FaveTeamID")]
    private int faveTeamID { get; set; }

    public static List<Members> MembersList = new List<Members>();

    public Members(string first, string last, string user, string pass, string email, string city, string state, string zip, string phone, int team)
    {
        //memberID = id;
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
        userName = user;
        password = pass;
        this.email = email;
        memberCity = city;
        memberState = state;
        memberZip = zip;
        memberPhone = phone;
        faveTeamID = team;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Member: " + userName + " in " + memberCity;
    }

    public bool compareUserAndPassword(string currUser, string currPass)
    {
        if (currUser.Equals(userName) && currPass.Equals(password))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here's my server-side data object:

```
public partial class Member
{
    public int MemberID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(32)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public int FavTeamID { get; set; }
}
```

I know this is a lot of code, but I'd rather post too much than too little.  One thought I had was to somehow add the MemberID value to the httpClient object and pass that as a parameter to other pages, but I'm not sure if that's possible either.  How can I get the MemberID value for a specific member if that value is only stored in the server-side data object but not in the client-side model?  I'm open to different approaches as well if there's an easier way to go about this.  Thank you in advance for your help.

UPDATE

My issue seems to be originating from my GetMemberIDByName method in my controller.  When I debugged it, I got the following error message:

Cannot call action method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[T] GetMemberIDByNameT' on controller 'WorkingVersionGetItDone.Controllers.MembersController' because the action method is a generic method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your method should look more like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMemberIDByName(string MemberStr)
{
    var member = await db.Members.Where(x => x.UserName == MemberStr).ToListAsync();
    if (member == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(member[0].MemberID);
}
```

The caller will then either get a 404 (the `NotFound()`) or a 200 with a payload of the `MemberID` and you can process appropriately.

```
HttpResponseMessage memberResponse = await client.GetAsync("api/Members?MemberStr=" + currUser);

if(memberResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    // got the memberId...
    var memberId = Convert.ToInt32( memberResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
else if(memberResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    // member not found...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's pretty similar to what I came up with.  Do you know how I can get that value in my client code?  My server is now returning to correct value (<int>101</int>), but I'm having trouble obtaining that value in my client code.  Any ideas?

Comment: See the updates I made to the response. I should point out that the `GetMemberIDByName` code is pretty fragile as it makes an assumption that you'll get 0 or 1 members for the `MemberStr`. If you happen to get > 1 you'll just randomly grab the first one.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't see that at first.  I used the code you mentioned, but it never hits OK or NotFound.  I imported System.Net for HttpStatusCode.  I also tried importing Windows.Net.Http instead, but that caused even more issues.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Disregard that last comment.  I had a typo that I fixed when copying your code and now it works.  Thanks.